# Http Post to Server json with android

Tags: php, android, json, curl

i´m trying to do post a request in a webservice, actually i can do `$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"root","password":"8246"}' https://192.168.1.5:8000/token/ --insecure`

in a terminal and get a authentication token response, but.. how i can do this with android studio?, i´ve seen too many example codes downloading things but i want to authenticate a user in my RESTful service.
Thanks

i've tried httpconnection but is now deprecated by android studio, and i cant find how to do it correctly with okhttp, if you have an example or something would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use a library like [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http), [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Those libs will take care of not blocking your UI thread and much more.

There's plenty of tutorials on them, just try and ask again if you run into any troubles :)

Comment: By the way, imho AsynHttpClient will be the easiest to use.

Comment: I used [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it works well more especially accessing https check an example on [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the meat of the code you will need to execute your network request.  You can do it in a runnable or an async task.  Whatever your preference is just make sure not to run it on the UI thread.

```
mPostRequest = new HttpPost("some url");
mPostRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(json);
mPostRequest.setEntity(postingString);
mResponse = httpClient.execute(mPostRequest);
```

Comment: thanks mate, but thats deprecated in the new version of android studio.